# How can I describe a reference in a node to another one?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML format I need to parse. An example file is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<root>
  <parent name="example1">
   <childdef ref="1" type="a" />
   <childdef ref="3" type="c" />
  </parent>

  <parent name="example2">
   <childdef ref="1" type="b" />
   <childdef ref="2" type="b" />
  </parent>

  <child id="1" name="Child 1" />
  <child id="2" name="Child 2" />
  <child id="3" name="Child 3" />
  <child id="4" name="Child 4" />
</root>
```

The `parent` elements contain at least one `childdef` element that refers to a child element. You must use a reference, because one child can be referenced by several parents (see child 1).

If I now use an XML mapper (e.g. a JAXB implementation), I would like to have a Object reference from Parent1 to Child 1. Now I only have the reference id as an attribute.

Is it possible to define this object reference in the XSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. See [`@XmlID`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.html) and [`@XmlIDREF`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlIDREF.html). They correspond to the XML types `xsd:id` and `xsd:idref`. But keep in mind that only strings can be IDs.

Comment: Thanks! This will help me. Is it possible to specify the type of the referenced Object? Now JAXB only gives an Object...

Comment: I don't understand. `@XmlIDREF` can be on a field of any type that has a `@XmlID`.